# IIS Redirect with a fall back?

Tags: redirect, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

On a website I help support, they have country based websites (en-de, en-au) which they want to shut off a redirect to the main two which are en-gb and en-us.

The website runs on a Microsoft server and tbh I am more Apache/PHP based. I have set up a redirect currently which redirect the en-au url and takes them to the same url on en-gb. So if they are on en-au/some-url it will send them to en-gb/some-url.

My only problem is if the same url does not exist for en-gb. Is there a way on IIS to set up a fallback? So if it leads to a 404 from the redirect it sends them to the homepage instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another url rewrite to handle the 404's, below will direct all 404's back to your homepage.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect404" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/YourHomePage.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

You can also add custom error pages to handle the 404's

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors/error